# Laravel: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to save my results in the database but im getting an error exception.

In my view I have a radio button(array) that gets the result of each student which is **present,late,absent,others**

**Here's my view**

```
  <td>{{ $users->student_id  }} </td>
  <td>{{ $users->student_firstname }} {{ $users->student_lastname }}</td> 
  <td>{{ Form::radio('result['.$users->student_id.']', 'present' , true) }}</td>
  <td>{{ Form::radio('result['.$users->student_id.']', 'late' ) }}</td>
  <td>{{ Form::radio('result['.$users->student_id.']', 'absent') }}</td>
  <td>{{ Form::radio('result['.$users->student_id.']', 'others') }}</td>
```

**Here's my controller**

```
  $attendance = new Attendances();
  $attendance->status = Input::get('result');
  $attendance->comment = Input::get('comment');
  $attendance->save();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your radio input `result` will return an array, due to the naming convention you have chosen.

If you wish to save the singular value of the input `result`, use the following format.

**View code:**

```
<td>{{ Form::radio('result', 'present' , true) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('result', 'late') }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('result', 'absent')   }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('result', 'others')  }}</td>
```

If you are expecting multiple values in an array, then you should be looping through the code, and saving each individually:

**Controller Code:**

```
foreach (Input::get('result') as $studentId=>$value)
{
     $attendance = new Attendances();
     $attendance->status = $value;
     $attendance->comment = Input::get('comment');
     //We should save the student id somewhere.
     $attendance->student_id = $studentId;
     $attendance->save();
}
```

**Suggestion:**

If you wish to save several student's information on the same form, the suggestion below will work great.

**View Code:**

```
<td>{{ $users->student_id  }} </td>
<td>{{ $users->student_firstname }} {{ $users->student_lastname }}</td> 
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'present' , true) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'late' ) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'absent') }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'others') }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::text('student['.$users->student_id.'][comment]'}}</td>
```

**Controller Code for saving**

```
//We loop through each student and save their attendance.
foreach (Input::get('student') as $studentId=>$data)
{
     $attendance = new Attendances();
     $attendance->status = $data['status'];
     $attendance->comment = $data['comment'];
     //We should save the student id somewhere.
     $attendance->student_id = $studentId;
     $attendance->save();
}
```

Comment: How can i save if my naming convention are arrays? :/

Comment: Radio inputs return a single value. Is there any reason why you went with `'result['.$users->student_id.']'` for the radio's name?

Comment: The reason i went for that is because I want each student in the table to have different/same results when recording attendance within the section (e.g. student1 is present, student2 is late)

Comment: Added a solution to the answer.

Comment: Okay wait let me try :)

Comment: I got an error saying:  Undefined index: status  :(

Comment: Fixed the **view code**. Had to remove quotes on the name of the inputs. Tested and working.

Comment: Thank you it works :)  but however, the results are not exactly that i wanted :(    
its counting the arrays which are (present,absent,late,others) not the number of students which is 2 :(  

However, Thanks for the code it really helps a lot :)

Comment: You'll have to write some php code to obtain that count. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, where using

```
$attendance->fill(array with non-existing columns);
```

sets a non-existing column value, so on calling

```
$attendance->save();
```

afterwards, it will throw that error