# Insert array in BD Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to add a array data in a BD

I have this code

```
$id=$usuario->id;
$datereg = date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
$dateact = date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
$idcat = array($request->input ( 'cat' ));
$sqlInsert = array(
    array('id'=>$id, 'idcat'=>$idcat, 'datereg'=>$datereg,'dateact'=>$dateact),
);

//DB::statement ( "INSERT INTO intereses (usuario_movil_id,categorias_id, fecha_registro, fecha_actualizacion) VALUES ('$id', '$idcat','$datereg','$dateact')" );

foreach ( $sqlInsert as $row ) {

    DB::statement(
            "INSERT INTO intereses (usuarios_movil_id,categorias_id, fecha_registro, fecha_actualizacion) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ? )",
            array($row['id'], $row['idcat'], $row['datereg'], $row['dateact'])
    );

}
```

This code shows me that error "preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array"

Any Idea?

Comment: It is looking to insert a string and you're providing it an array. You might find this answer helpful I hope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620335/laravel-preg-replace-parameter-mismatch-pattern-is-a-string-while-replaceme

Comment: Im modified the code

Answer (score 0):

Im modified the code

```
$id=$usuario->id;
            $datereg = date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
            $dateact = date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
            $idcat = array($request->input ( 'cat' ));
            $sqlInsert = 
                    array('idcat'=>$idcat);
                //DB::statement ( "INSERT INTO intereses (usuario_movil_id,categorias_id, fecha_registro, fecha_actualizacion) VALUES ('$id', '$idcat','$datereg','$dateact')" );

                foreach ( $idcat as $row=>$value ) {

                    DB::statement(
                            "INSERT INTO intereses (usuarios_movil_id,categorias_id, fecha_registro, fecha_actualizacion) VALUES ('$id', '".$row[$request->input ( 'cat' )]."', '$datereg', '$dateact' )"
                            //array($id, $row['idcat'], $datereg, $dateact)
                    );

                }
```

And now the value for ''categorias_id'' its empty

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of the following line

```
$idcat = array($request->input ( 'cat' ));
```

it should not be an array. try this:

```
$idcat = $request->input ( 'cat' )
```