# Laravel update database error - Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am fetching rows from the database. Each row has 2 radio buttons. I am having issues updating these values in a table. I get this error -

preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

```
@foreach($items as $item)                 
    <td>{{ $item->item_title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->total }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class='btn-group'>
                <form action="{{url('lineManagerUpdateRequests')}}" method="post">

                <input type="radio" name="item_id[{{$item->request_id}}][]" value="2"> Approve
                <input type="radio" name="item_id[{{$item->request_id}}][]" value="6"> Decline
            </div>
        </td>    
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
</form>
```

This is my controller

```
    foreach ($request->input('item_id') as $id => $value) {
            $update = DB::table('request_items')
                        ->where('id', $id)
                        ->update(['line_manager_remark', $value]);

   }
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29620335/1531971

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change here , provide array

```
   ->update(['line_manager_remark'=>$value]);
```

Check here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#updates

Comment: What should I change here?

Comment: He changed that line. What you passed to update() was an array with two elements; he passed an associative array with one element of index "line_manager_remark"

Comment: The `=>` symbol instead `,`

Comment: What you get in `$request->input('item_id') , $id and in $value` ?

Answer (score 0):

problem is in your html form. replace your input tag with below code.

```
<input type="radio" name="item_id[{{$item->request_id}}]" value="2"> Approve
<input type="radio" name="item_id[{{$item->request_id}}]" value="6"> Decline
```

`item_id[{{$item->request_id}}][]` in your html form creates and submits multidimensional array. so $value in controller foreach contains an array not a string.

**update**

make above change and edit your update method as below :

```
 ->update(['line_manager_remark'=>$value]);
```

Comment: Both input belongs to same element now.